# Is there some function to create a simple calculator without eval

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript and I'm trying to create a simple calculator with a **separated function of operation**
example for `sum` and `subtraction` function

```js
fonction calculator() {
  this.addition = function(param1, param2) {
    .........
  }
  this.subtraction = function(param1, param2) {
    .........
  }
}
```

and like this for division **without using an eval function** .

i have made a lot of try without any result
my code :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRderx

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages. This has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: `return param1 + param2` in the `addition` function and `return param1 - param2` in the `subtraction` function?

Comment: Your code does not appear to include the addition or subtraction methods. *What have you tried?*

Answer (score 1):

Separate the display logic from the operational logic.

Extremely simple example:

```js
const input = '22*7';
const operands = input.split('*');
const result = operands[0] * operands[1];
console.log(result);
```

Because you have an interface for this to be defined, I would suggest not splitting the string, but having your input create an array of 'operands' and 'operators' that can then build a string from, with the result being easily consumable for calculating the result, for instance

Simple example: `[22, 'x', 15, '*', 2];

The output string could then easily be shown using `.join('')`

```js
const view = [55, '+', 22, '*', 2].join('');
console.log(view);
```

The challenge here will likely be determining order of operation. A recursive solution might prove useful for this.

Comment: can u give please a simple exemple in my code here :https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRderx