# How to create a calculator without eval() in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How are you?
I'm a little new to JavaScript and Vue and I'm having a little trouble switching from using eval() to something more secure. I read in forums and documentation that it is not good to use it but I am not able to replace it in the calculator I created. Could anyone help me out on what to do? Thank you.
This is my code and I tryed use this question

> [Is there some function to create a simple calculator without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308695/is-there-some-function-to-create-a-simple-calculator-without-eval)

to change the eval() but I wasn't able to

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      getOperation: "",
      getResult: "0",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleClickAC() {
      this.getResult = "0";
    },
    handleClick(par) {
      if (this.getResult === "0") {
        this.getResult = par;
      } else {
        this.getResult += par;
      }
    },
    handleClickDel() {
      if (this.getResult.length > 1) {
        this.getResult = this.getResult.substring(0, this.getResult.length - 1);
      } else {
          this.getResult = '0'
      }
    },
    handleClickResult() {
        let operation = this.getResult
        this.getOperation = operation
        operation = operation.replace('x', '*')
        this.getResult = eval(operation)
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>{{ getOperation }}</p>
        <p >{{ getResult }}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="botoes">
        <button @click="handleClickAC()">AC</button>
        <button @click="handleClickDel()">DEL</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('/')">/</button>

        <button @click="handleClick('7')">7</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('8')">8</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('9')">9</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('x')">X</button>

        <button @click="handleClick('4')">4</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('5')">5</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('6')">6</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('-')">-</button>

        <button @click="handleClick('3')">3</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('2')">2</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('1')">1</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('-')">+</button>

        <button @click="handleClick('0')">0</button>
        <button @click="handleClick('.')">.</button>
        <button @click="handleClickResult()">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: The question you linked already contains the solution. This is the way this needs to be done. Did you try it? What did not work? As for eval, it doesn't cause security issues here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there some function to create a simple calculator without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308695/is-there-some-function-to-create-a-simple-calculator-without-eval)

Comment: See my answer to another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73495791/456536

Comment: https://medium.com/@stoopidguy1992/how-to-write-a-math-expression-parser-in-javascript-b5147bc9466b