# Is it safe to use eval for a client-side JavaScript calculator?

Tags: javascript, security, eval, client-side

I was making a calculator which was served as a static HTML page to the user's browser.  The page is not designed to submit any information back to the server.  Nothing else will be present on the web page except for this calculator.

Is it safe to use "eval" in this scenario? Or put another way, does the use of eval in this case cause additional security risk?

To me, it doesn't seem like the user can do anything nefarious with this page they can't do by simply opening the browsers development tools.  I have always read "never" use eval, but in this case, it seems like it makes good sense.

Here is an example calculator:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="input" type="text">
    <button onclick="{
        let result= '';
        try {
            result = eval(document.getElementById('input').value);
        } catch (error) {
            result = error;
        }
        console.log(result);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=result;
        }">calculate</button>
    <div id="result">result here</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I also made a calculator with JavaScript in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73495791/456536). ScriptCalculator: https://iwill.im/url/2, GitHub: https://github.com/iwill/ScriptCalculator

Answer (score 1):

It will potentially open up the page to arbitrary code execution. Consider if someone manages to convince one of your users or a few: "Try pasting in this into the input field. You won't believe what happens next!" That's a big potential problem if you save *any* user-related data on the client - such as login credentials in a cookie, or data in Local Storage or IndexedDB, etc.

Even if you don't store any such data, it'd probably be a good idea to sanitize the input value so that it only contains mathematical expressions, and nothing else. For example, it'd be trivial to permit only numbers and operators you want, maybe `+-*/`. It's so easy to do and makes things safe, so you should do it.

Also, don't put functions into inline handlers (or use inline handlers at all) - they're quite poor practice. Attach event listeners properly using `addEventListener`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const sanitizedValue = document.getElementById('input').value
    .replace(/[^-+/*\d]/g, '');
  try {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = eval(sanitizedValue);
  } catch(e) {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Syntax not correct';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button>calculate</button>
<div id="result">result here</div>
```

`.replace(/[^-+/*\d]/g, '');` does:

- Match any character that is not:

  - `-`, `+`, `/`, `*`
  - Or `\d` (any digit)
- Replace all such matched characters with the empty string

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It is great advice.  I hadn't thought about the client-side storage and cookies aspect.  Regarding "That's a big potential problem if you save any user-related data on the client".  Does using the eval(expression) in an input like this pose any additional risk than opening browser developer tools and using eval(expression) in the console?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `eval` inside a webpage's script is moderately safer, because it'll only have access to the website's data. But the console has more privileges, and will have access to the top window, without any CORS restrictions. If an attacker can get a victim to paste some code into their console, the victim's probably lost, no matter whether the code pasted includes `eval` or not (not that there'd be any reason to have `eval` if the attacker has that level of access)

Answer (score 0):

***Never use `eval()`!***

It is [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!), and it also said:

> Fortunately, there's a very good alternative to `eval()`: using the `Function` constructor.

So, you can replace `eval()` like this:

```js
let result= '';
try {
    result = Function(`"use strict";return (${document.getElementById('input').value})`)();
}
catch (error) {
    result = error;
}
```

It's almost the same as the `eval`, except that:

> In the function without the `eval()`, the object is being evaluated in the global scope, so it is safe

Comment: Using the function constructor is not very different security-wise from `eval`. They both allow for arbitrary code execution. Whether the arbitrary code runs in the global scope or not, a potential attacker will still be able to scrape all user data you have on that domain and many do other nasty things. No matter if one uses `eval` or the function constructor, if the code is malicious, you're in deep trouble regardless.